# update fields on clicking of tabs

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, managed-package

We have an SFDC Community setup where they have multiple tabs available to the users. One of those tabs is a managed package tab around training. This managed package requires licenses in order to take the training.

Is it possible that if the license is currently inactive on the Community User record, for the license to be reactivated by the Community User just clicking on the tab in the Salesforce Community?

Comment: Search for "installed package". there you will see an option for "manage license" in front of the package which has that tab. by that option you can manage the licenses assigned to the users.

Comment: I want to assign the license to the user when it is created, unassigned it when he does not log in for a while and assign it again when he tries to access the restricted part I am able to do first two functionalities and now want to achieve the third one so as top complete the flow.